# Simple jQuery Modal Window not showing popup on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with one of the jQuery Modal Window as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

It works fine with the basic example but when i make changes to show the Modal window on page load then it does not work, It even blocks the link `<a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Modal Window</a>` from showing popup modal if clicked on.

I have example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJhvJ/)

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

I simply want simple modal window to show up on page load event.

```
launchWindow('#dialog');  // does not work as shown in that tutorial
```

Comment: have you tried checking for errors in your console?

Comment: are you using the document.ready function since it has to be called only when the elements are ready

Comment: Try to put some code it will be easier to help

Comment: The reason why the modal is working on page loaded is that it would only work if you have click the link.  I tried to run your code, the error seems to be on the launchWindow('#dialog') , did you define such function?

Comment: I have example of jsFiddle

Comment: @Kyeljmd, I dont want the link so show up on page i actually  want to use this script to show Notice board message to user.

Comment: I see, but on your code, the dialog or the notice board would only show up when you click the anchor tag.  You can however, get all the code inside the  onclick and just paste it on your document.ready, rather than registering the event to show up on onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this: **http://jsfiddle.net/HJUZm/**

you have that on click of the `<a>` just removed that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect    
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);   
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);


//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask, .window').hide();
});    

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});        

$(window).resize(function () {

    var box = $('#boxes .window');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    box.css('top',  winH/2 - box.height()/2);
    box.css('left', winW/2 - box.width()/2);

});    
});
```

Comment: this is what I am telling to poster, the modal would only work if he clicks the a tag.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that one. I will mark your answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

In your code it is missing the function `launchWindow()`. This is the function:

```
function launchWindow(id) { 
        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height());
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this it works on page load as u described
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJhvJ/2/)

```
Here simply I have removed     `$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {` });
```

and has set `var id = $('#link').attr('href');` where link id is id of the  tag

Answer (score 0):

**launchWindow(..)** is not defined in your javascript.

instead try this: 
$('a[name=modal]').click();

Comment: What the user is aiming to do is that on page load, the modal would be shown, not by clicking the anchor tag.

Comment: Yes, the above code indirectly calls the click event of the link. This is if he wants both onLoad and also link to available to show popup